# PHP どんなケースでも正常に通る配列の隣合う２つの数字の足し算を実装したい。

Tags: php

## 前提条件

サンプルコードでは$Aが[1,3,5,7]と定義されていますが、これはあくまで一例で、$Aの要素の数は動的に変化します。
また$A[]の値は1~1000までのint型とします。

## やりたいこと

$Aの要素数が変化しても、配列の隣り合う数を要素数が一つになるまで足し算したいです。
図で表すと下記みたいな感じです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

仮に$A[]に8が追加されてしまう場合、下記のサンプルコードだと要素数が残り２つになり、テストケースが通らなくなってしまいます。

### サンプルコード1

```php
<?php
$A = [1, 3, 5, 7];
// echo count($A);
$one = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($A) - 1; $i++) {
 // echo $A[$i] + $A[$i+1] . PHP_EOL;
 $one[] = $A[$i] + $A[$i + 1];
}
// print_r($one);

$two = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($one) - 1; $i++) {
 // echo $one[$i] + $one[$i+1] . PHP_EOL;
 $two[] = $one[$i] + $one[$i + 1];
}
// print_r($two);

$three = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($two) - 1; $i++) {
 // echo $two[$i] + $two[$i+1] . PHP_EOL;
 $three[] = $two[$i] + $two[$i + 1];
}

print_r($three);
```

サンプルの結果

```
Array
(
    [0] => 32
)
```

## サンプルコード2

$A[]に８を追加した場合、

```php
$A = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8];

// 以下全て同じなので省略
```

結果 => forの数が足りず結果の要素数が２つになってしまう。サンプル２の結果を、サンプル１の結果を変えないまま32+47で79になるようにしたいです。

```
Array
(
    [0] => 32
    [1] => 47
)
```

この問題を解決するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は配列の pairwise(隣同士の要素をペアにする)を取る方法です。

```php
<?php
$A = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8];

for($arr=$A;count($arr)>1;) {
  $arr = array_map(
    function($a, $b) {
      return $a + $b;
    }, array_slice($arr, 0, -1), array_slice($arr, 1));
}

print_r($arr);

=>

Array
(
    [0] => 79
)
```